# Which routes should I use in rails match :controller(/:action(/:id)) or resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am using match `:controller(/:action(/:id))` as routing system.

I didn't see anyone using this type of routing system. All are using resources routes.

Is this the best way to make routing or what is the best preference for routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [RESTful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) you are missing :)

Answer (score 1):

[`Deprecate method "match" in routes.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964)

> ... proposal is to announce 'match' method in routes.rb as deprecated and
> later(e.g. rails 5.0) put it to "private methods" section.
>
> It will encourage people to use "pure" restful methods-verbs like put
> post get etc and will raise knowledge of their meaning and goal. (GET
> for retrieving data, POST for state changing requests)
>
> Why? - my points are described at http://homakov.blogspot.ru/2012/04/whitelist-your-routes-match-is-evil.html

Answer (score 1):

I think @AndreyDeineko provided a good answer.

Another problem with `match :controller(/:action(/:id))` I noticed a while ago, is that it might lead to security issues:

Imagine you have methods your `application_controller.rb` that are not marked as `private`. Since all other controllers inherit from `ApplicationController` everyone can call these methods just by guessing names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @spickerman. I will change my routes to resources

Answer (score 1):

You can use any routes you want unless you are creating an API. If you are creating an API, you need RESTful routes. resources provides you with restful routes.